# Angular: prevent selecting radio buttons in radio group

Tags: angular, radio-button, radio-group

I have following radio group. User should be allowed to select only the second radio button. When any other radio button is selected, all the radio buttons should be unchecked including the second radio button. So far I did following.

```typescript
    public listOfOptions = [
        { name: 'some name 1', ID: 'D1', checked: false },
        { name: 'some name 2', ID: 'D2', checked: false },
        { name: 'some name 3', ID: 'D3', checked: false },
        { name: 'some name 4', ID: 'D4', checked: false },
      ];

      selectButton(op) {
        console.log(op.name);
        if (op.name === 'some name 2') {
          op.checked = true;
          return true;
        } else {
          op.checked = false;
          return false;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <mat-radio-group name="opList">
      <mat-radio-button
        name="opList"
        *ngFor="let op of listOfOptions"
        [checked]="op.checked"
        [value]="op.checked"
        (change)="selectButton(op)"
        >{{ op.name }}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have references to all your checkboxes to set them, currently you only set the one that was clicked, or create a FormArray for your data and patchValue on that if the second is clicked. Also youre naming all your checkboxes the same name...

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms